# I need to find a maximum value of the column and need to determine the first name and laste name of a person that has a maximum value

Tags: python, pandas

I am  trying to find a maximum value of a cloumn called Height from table Data and i write this code

```
maxi=max(Data['Height'])
```

I find the maximum height from this. I am trying to find the first name and last name of a person that has a maximum height using iloc but i am not being able to do it.

I did this

```
location=Maximum.iloc[Maximum, 'FirstName LastName']
```

But it is not working

Comment: Use `data['height'].argmax()` to get the index.

Comment: It give the index but it doesn't give the first name and last name

Comment: `data.loc[data['height'].argmax(),['FirstName','LastName']]`